# Parse Json array using angular http.get

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Can any one tell me how to parse [this API](https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2) using `Angular`. I want to get all `unis` array elements.

```
$http.get('https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2').success(function(data)
{
    console.log("UniCtrl:" + data.unis);
    $scope.unis = data.unis;
});
```

But `data.unis` is showing as `undefind`.

Comment: You might have to parse `data` as JSON.

Comment: @Bibhas thanx, can you tell me how.

Comment: hmm, that api return content-type application/json it should automatically parse json data though.

Comment: @YOU I can't fetch the output from terminal because of SSL error. Is it possible that data is not being returned for the same reason?

Comment: but there is no `access-control-allow-origin:*`, i guess you need jsonp if they are supported if are requesting from different domain.

Comment: i am also facing access-control-allow-origin:* this error in chrome and response is not coming. how can we solve this.

Comment: if they dont support jsonp, its not possible for javascript, as far as i know.

Comment: @YOU so no way to parse this..

Comment: not parsing issue, you are not getting the data through xhr. if you try console.log(data), it should be undefined or something blank too.

Comment: @YOU so what is the solution.\

Comment: If there is no public api, you need middle layer, that fetch that json from server like php or python and that pass data through to your web.

Comment: What is your `data` is return?

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.jsonp('https://www.coursera.org/maestro/api/topic/list2').success(function(data) {
    JSON.parse(data); // to parse it
    console.log(data); // to see what it returns
    $scope.unis = data.unis;
});
```

Comment: @decodesmith not working giving error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :